# WindowsIdentity constructor throws exception with token from LogonUser

Tags: c#, pinvoke, windows-identity

I'm running inside a command line application that authenticates users using `LogonUser`. The function returns correctly and *fails* correctly (invalid user name or password).  When I pass the token returned by the `LogonUser` function into the `WindowsIdentity(IntPtr)` constructor, I receive the error:

> Invalid token for impersonation - it
>   cannot be duplicated.

I've tried duplicating the token before passing it into the `WindowsIdentity` constructor using the `DuplicateToken` function. This fails as well. I have UAC on and am running Windows 7 x64. Running as both admin and not admin yields the same result.

Some additonal info:

- Logging into a domain
- Using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`
- Using `LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being environmental. DNS issue while attempting to authenticate against the domain. A reset of the development box fixed the issue.

Comment: I had this happen too and this helped resolve it. I was also getting weird SChannel errors in Event Viewer under Windows Logs -> System. A reboot fixed both it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you, or recreate the issue?

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

// ...

IntPtr token;
LogonUser(Username, Domain, Password, 8, 0, out token)

WindowsIdentity wi;
wi = new WindowsIdentity(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error only in code compiled using in .Net Framework 4. There was no error when compiled with all previous versions.

this code used to fail in .net 4:

```
using(WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(accessToken))
    context = identity.Impersonate();
```

However, I found that this works:

```
context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(accessToken);
```

Comment: This suggestion made no difference for me; still got the same exception.